# Не получается энергия как TotM

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Хотел сделать энергию как в игре TotM. Если мы не знаете что эта за игра то расскажу кратко, У нас есть энергия и за то что мы проигрываем у нас она отнимается. Пытался делать через PlayerPrefs, но в тот момент когда должна была быть смерть(то есть в момент соприкосновения коллайдеров) Она отнимается, но после перезагрузки уровня она не отнимается больше.

Comment: Без кода здесь вряд-ли что-то можно сказать, ну разве что кроме "используйте отладку"

Comment: @Фёдор К, добавьте код.